# Why are my Keyevents not working?

Tags: java, key, switch-statement, keyevent

I am working on a game in Java which uses Keyevents. Basically, it is a template which I wanted to enhance but now I am struggling with some basic stuff. Here it goes:

In the keyPressed() method are a number of events, like this:

```
public void keyPressed(int key) {
    switch (key) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_A:
        System.out.println("A");
        methodA();
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_B:
        System.out.println("B");
        methodB();
        break;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to add another KeyEvent, like `KeyEvent.VK_1` , it does not work/ the key is not recognized. Why is that? Am I missing something?

Comment: What doesn't work ? Maybe you should have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: your code even is a KeyEvent type

Comment: Are you not able to respond to any other keys? Or just the number keys? If Swing, have you considered using Key Bindings? Which `1` are you trying to recognize? The one on the top of the keyboard or the one on the number pad to the side? This makes a difference actually.

Comment: I am trying to use the `1`from the top

Comment: If you are overriding `keyPressed` method of `KeyListener` then it is wrong ..It should be `public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt)` . So my Question : Is `keyPressed` a user defined method in your class?

Comment: You're missing the rest of my questions.

Comment: @user2426316, as Hoevercraft has already suggested, Key Bindings is almost always the way to go for something like a game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyListener` has a well know issue. In order to receive key events, the component it is register to must be focusable and have focus. It is also possible for the key event to be consumed before it reaches your listener (by the component you are registered to).

Instead, you should be [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which will, give you greater flexibility in determining how key events are handled

Comment: `It is also possible for the key event to be consumed before it reaches your listener` Does it mean that sometimes the `KeyListener` methods are not called up even though the `KeyEvent` is fired by associated component?

Comment: Yes. Because the key listeners are chained, if one of them consumes the event, then others may not not be it offed. Tis will come down to how the event is being dispatched, but I tripped over this one in my early years of Swing